# Flask + SQLAlchemy + Sqlite объект не добавляется в базу

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

Я постараюсь очень кратко, код будет обрывочным, постараюсь не лить лишнее. Скажу лишь, что построчно все проверял в консоли, ошибки приложу ниже. Есть у меня класс с пятью полями, первое и пятое понятно.

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article %r>' % (self.id)
```

Форма заполнения объекта:

```
<form action="/create-article" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control"></br>
<textarea name="intro" id="intro" class="form-control"></textarea></br>
<textarea name="text" id="text" class="form-control"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Отправить">
```

Затем при методе post просто создаю объект заполненными полями

```
def create_article():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        intro = request.form['intro']
        text = request.form['text']

        article = Article(title=title, intro=intro, text=text)
        with app.app_context():
            try:
                db.session.add(article)
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect('/')
            except:
                return 'Error'
    else:
        return render_template('create-article.html')
```

Сначала довольно долго не мог создать саму базу, как я понял, в новой версии Фласка такая проблема. Почитал документацию, приходится дописывать
`with app.app_context():`  иначе

> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
> the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
> `with app.app_context()`. See the documentation for more information.

Ну и при добавлении статьи в базу тоже идет только так.

Возвращает 'Error'

Пробовал все построчно в консоли, на шаге `db.session.commit()`  ошибка

```
> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: article
[SQL: INSERT INTO article (title, intro, text, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('title', 'intro', 'text', '2024-03-13 04:25:38.283046')]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Но экземпляр класса создан, к нему можно обращаться. Прикладываю скриншот.[image: лог]

Конечно, базу я создал после того, как разобрался с app_context

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///blog.db'
```

И в консоли в три поля просто вручную добавил одноименные строки, для теста.

Якобы объекта article не существует. Очень прошу помочь разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была из-за создания бд через сам .py файл. Чтобы избежать проблемы, **в терминале** поочередно введите команды

```
python
from app import app
from app import db
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

После двоеточия не забудьте четыре пробела или еретический таб. Файл должен создаться в проекте, и его размер не должен быть нулевым (как было у меня). Также при любых операциях с бд, обязательно нужно использовать конструкцию

```
with app.app_context():
    #операция с бд (добавление, удаление и тд)
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю из-за того что

> довольно долго не мог создать саму базу

база создалась, а таблица в базе не создалась.

 Можно в каком-нибудь редакторе sqlite добавить таблицу.
Можно создать и выполнить одноразовый скрипт:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,Table,MetaData, Column, String, Integer, Text, DateTime,select
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect
import datetime
# Создаем движок
engine=create_engine('sqlite:///mysqlite.db',echo=True)
metadata=MetaData()

# Описываем таблицу базы данных
article=Table('article', metadata,
     Column('id',Integer, primary_key=True),
     Column('title',String(100), nullable=False),
     Column('intro',String(300), nullable=False),
     Column('text',Text, nullable=False),
     Column('date',DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
              )

# Это если несколько раз запускать программу, проверка если таблица есть, то удалить и создать
inspector=inspect(engine)
if article.name in inspector.get_table_names():
     article.drop(bind=engine)
     article.create(bind=engine)
else:
     article.create(bind=engine)

#Записать тестовые данные
data=[{ 'title':'Здесь заголовок',
     'intro':'Коротко о главном',
     'text':'Основной текст'
       },
{ 'title':'Здесь другой заголовок',
     'intro':'Коротко о главном вторая запись',
     'text':'Основной текст полностью'
       }
      ]
insdata=article.insert().values(data)
with engine.begin() as con:
     con.execute(insdata)


#Вывести тестовые данные
with engine.begin() as con:
     res=con.execute(select(article))
     for el in res:
          print(el)
```

---

```
(1, 'Здесь заголовок', 'Коротко о главном', 'Основной текст', datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 13, 7, 30, 46, 674496))
(2, 'Здесь другой заголовок', 'Коротко о главном вторая запись', 'Основной текст полностью', datetime.datetime(2024, 3, 13, 7, 30, 46, 674496))
```

Чтобы логи не выводились, исправить `engine=create_engine('sqlite:///mysqlite.db',echo=False)`

Comment: я не понимаю самой сути проблемы. Предполагаю, что учебник, которым я пользуюсь, банально устарел, особенно учитывая проблему с with app.app_context(), которой раньше банально не было. Но более свежего материала я не нашел. Есть обычные функции, добавить и подтвердить, которые должны работать. Сама логика ведь верная. Может, есть смысл просто делать через sqlite3 и не париться? Да, там объем текста больше, но там не должно возникать подобных проблем.

Comment: @Emil Aliyev, `Может, есть смысл просто делать через sqlite3` у меня тоже стоит этот вопрос, пока смотрю обсуждения.